# How to run a task if a previous one fails in Apache Airflow

Tags: python, triggers, controls, airflow

I need to do the following:

Check if a server is up, if so I check if the Spark cluster in that server is up, case it's down I try to start it up, case it's already up I move forward to run my Spark job.

I though about creating a task to check if the Spark cluster is up (maybe trying to run a simple Spark job). If it fails I'd start the "Start Spark cluster" task.

I'm using Airflow but didn't find a way to trigger a task in case the previous one fails. Besides that I'd need to check the previous one in case it succeeds so it would branch to the Spark job task and skip the "Start Spark Cluster" task.

If you could provide some samples that's be great. I tried using trigger_rule and the branch operator but got nothing so far. Maybe because there's too few code examples about them on the web.

Thanks

Comment: Setting the trigger rule to all_failed or one_failed should do exactly what you want. Just create two tasks downstream and set one to success and one two failed for example.
Btw. If you say you are starting a cluster I assume you use a cloud provider. There should be better ways to check if the cluster is up, f.e. using the cloud vendors command line tool. If you are using GCP there are even airflow operators that start dataproc clusters and submit jobs.

Comment: Thanks Gindele, I'all try your approach. Regarding the cluster, we have a Standalone spark cluster running in our own server, no cloud. Anyway, if you have any suggestions they are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PythonBranhOperator.
Here is a code sample for your reference.

```
VALID_TEST_OUTPUT = 'valid-output'
INVALID_TEST_OUTPUT = 'invalid-test-output'


test_job=PythonOperator(
    ## your task
)

def select_branch_after_test(**kwargs):
    '''
    :return: returns the task_id to proceed with.
    '''
    if com.getoutput('hadoop fs -ls /user/praveen/.test_out/ | grep file1'):
        follow_previous_job = VALID_TEST_OUTPUT
    else:
        follow_previous_job = INVALID_TEST_OUTPUT
    return follow_previous_job


# branching based on successful test output
branching = BranchPythonOperator(task_id=BRANCH_TEST_OUTPUT,
                                 python_callable=select_branch_after_test,
                                 dag=dag)
branching.set_upstream(test_job)

valid_test_output = PythonOperator(
    task_id=VALID_TEST_OUTPUT,
    python_callable=lambda **kwargs: logging.info("test genereated valid output, proceeding with other steps"),
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)
valid_test_output.set_upstream(branching)

end_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id=END,
    python_callable=pipeline_run_time,
    provide_context=True,
    trigger_rule='one_success',  ## Important
    dag=dag)

invalid_test_output = PythonOperator(
    task_id=INVALID_TEST_OUTPUT,
    python_callable=lambda **kwargs: logging.info("test did not create valid output, completeing branching dag to other path"),
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)
invalid_test_output.set_upstream(branching)

valid_test_output.set_downstream(end_task)
invalid_test_output.set_downstream(end_task)
```

`